# How to divide a list into chunks of alternating sizes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I need to divide a string into chunks of unequal sizes, that is ,if in a for loop i meets a certain condition then the chunk should be of specific length otherwise of different length. Basically I need to create a 2d array(list) where I know the number of rows but don't know the number of columns as the length of string is unknown. I tried various methods on googling. Here is one I tried on own.

```
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = []
c=[]
def divide_chunks(l): 
      
    # looping till length l 
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        j = 0
        if(i%2==0):
           while(j<4 and i<=len(l)):
               b.append(l.pop())
               i = i+1
        else:
              while(j<2 and i<=len(l)):
               b.append(l.pop())
               i = i+1
        c.append(b)
```

The problem I am facing is that the numbers or lets say words in case of string are getting overlapped in each chunk. For example one of the output is

> [[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]]

So I want to achieve something like if string is markisgoodboy. Then for first row it will take "mark" second row "is" and third row "good" and fourth row "bo" and last row "y". Please take note that it is row wise. The length of rows will be supplied as an argument for every method call. How to solve it ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe it is me but I do not understand if you want to split strings or lists, your conditions for splitting, where they are stored, when the conditions apply and when they don't, and how the last two examples (`[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` and `markisgoodboy`) relate to the question. But apart from this...

Comment: @Mr.T the logic would be still the same right ? Irrespective of string or list, I will still loop over it in same way I believe. So if I know the number of rows then I can store 4 elements in [0,0 ]row and one element in 1st row and again 4 in second. So i%2 == 0 will be for oth and 2 and so one. If you simply write the string in rows of 4 like M a r k one below other ,then that is what I am trying to say. Thank you :)

Comment: And how do we know that row 0 has 4 elements etc? Where is this information (for mark it seems to be `[4, 2, 4, 2, 1]`) stored? Or is it always 4-2 until the list/string is exhausted? This is not mentioned in your question. And regarding lists or strings - some methods work on both but others are only applicable to one or the other.

Comment: @Mr.T the length of rows will be fixed for every method call or you can say I know the length of rows be, so for the moment lets consider it as 4. Now how many words will be in subsequent row will be based upon the number of rows, So lets say something like len(rows) - 2 . But lets consider 2 for now. Can we make it generic for string and int list ? If not lets do it for string right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for both, lists and strings that don't contain empty elements:

```
def chunks(s, m, n):
    s1 = [s[i:i+m] for i in range(0, len(s), m+n)] 
    s2 = [s[i+m:i+m+n] for i in range(0, len(s), m+n)] 
    return [e for t in zip(s1, s2) for e in t if e]

s = '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'
m = 4
n = 2

print(chunks(list(s), m, n))
print(chunks(s, m, n))
```

Sample output:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9', '0'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], ['M', 'N'], ['O']]
['1234', '56', '7890', 'AB', 'CDEF', 'GH', 'IJKL', 'MN', 'O']
```

Comment: Thanks , what I was l looking for.:) can you please explain how this works -> s[i:i+m] ? I am relatively naïve in Python. I know it is for slicing, but need to understand the logic in the context.

Comment: The syntax is `x[start:stop:step]`, so in this case, just `x[start:stop]`. `s1` extracts the elements `(m+n)*i` to `(m+n)*i+m-1`, `s2` extracts the elements `(m+n)*i+m` to `(m+n)*i+m+n-1` for `i=0,1,2...`. Afterward, zip combines alternating elements of the two lists.

Comment: T sure will do it.